# break start command if execution fails in dos command

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, command

Consider `a.exe` is not present in the folder `D:\temp`

```
    cd /d D:\temp
    .\a.exe
    .\b.exe
```

I want to execute `a.exe` first, and I have to wait for its completion, and then i want to execute `b.exe`. If consider `a.exe` is not there in that path then its throwing the error message as below and then it start executing the next command `b.exe`.

```
    .\a.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

But If I execute that exe with start its showing error message in one dialog box.

```
    cd /d D:\temp
    start /wait .\a.exe
    start /wait .\b.exe
```

I dont want this behaviour. I want to execute with `start /wait`only, but if that exe is not there it has to return to the next command.

Note :
I dont want to check whether exe is present or not before running, like metioned below

```
    cd /d D:\temp
    IF NOT EXIST .\a.exe exit 1
    start /wait .\a.exe
    start /wait .\b.exe
```

Comment: Why not? : "I dont want to check whether exe is present or not before running, like metioned below"

Comment: So you want to know if a.exe is there but you don't want to check if it's there? Sounds a bit contradicting to me. What's the problem with checking if a.exe is there?

Comment: I want to know is there any way to escape from that error message dialog box. Because in my batch file, i will be calling lot of exe files, so i dont want to check whether exe is present or not.

Comment: Is this in a command file, or are you typing these commands by hand?  In a command file, you don't need to use start /wait; it will wait anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I know that batch script execution will wait even if i am not using `start /wait` for the execution. But i want this to be execution should happen on the new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will avoid the dialog box:

```
start /wait cmd /c .\a.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
./a.exe 2> nul
```

This way of invoking supresses the error message.

Comment: `./a.exe 2> nul` is not returning any error message. But I tried 'start ./a.exe 2>null` this one is returning error message in dialog box